# Html post array empty

Tags: php, html

I am trying to post HTML to another php and the $_POST array is empty.

```
<?php for($i = 0;$i<count($plans);$i++) { ?>
<form id="<?php echo "cart-form-" . $i ?>" method="post" action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>browse">
<div class="four columns">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $plans[$i]->id; ?>">
<ul class="pricing-table">
<li class="header item"><?php echo $plans[$i]->header ?></li>
<li class="item"><?php echo $plans[$i]->price; ?></li>
<li class="item"><?php echo $plans[$i]->description; ?></li>
<li class="pricing-table-button"><button class="std-button" type="submit">Buy</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

On the browse page, i got empty array.

```
print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
print "DATA: <pre>";
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
print "</pre>";
```

Rendered HTML

```
<form id="cart-form-0" action="/browseselection" method="post">
   <div class="four columns">
   <input id="id" value="1" name="id">
    <ul class="pricing-table">
     <li class="header item">Product ABC</li>
     <li class="item">$123</li>
     <li class="item">5</li>
     <li class="pricing-table-button">
       <button class="std-button" type="submit">Buy</button>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your rendered HTML?

Comment: Perhaps the user is being redirected after submitting the form. Try doing "echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];" on the browse page to make sure the request method really is POST.

Comment: to further the comment from @Otome try `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: Why is it being redirected and how?

Comment: action="/browseselection" really you want this form to be submitted to this page?

Comment: I don't see `type=hidden` in the rendered output.

Answer (score 0):

The only value you can receive through this form is the "value" attribute of the input:

```
<?php echo $plans[$i]->id; ?>
```

if this has any data.

Test with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="testing data">
```

Then, the page browse has to output:

```
$_POST['id']= "testing data"
```